# Unity - don't load the same assetbundle twice

Tags: bundle, unity-game-engine, assets

I am having problems with downloading assetbundles.

I get the error:

```
The asset bundle 'url/levelpackIphone-Copy.unity3d' can't be loaded because
another asset bundle with the same files are already loaded
```

I need to check if the asset bundle has already been downloaded. My problem is that I cannot just store the URL, because the file you download can have a different name, but still contain the same content.

Thus somehow I need to check whether the asset bundle already has been downloaded.
I don't really like to use something like

```
bundle.Unload(false);
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for that. I didn't know unity != unity3d. I thought they were the same. :)

Comment: Sounds like reorganising the bundle structure would be the best choice if possible at all. Then you could use additive loading.

Comment: Yes, well, it is very unlikely this problem will exists in the full version of what I am building, because now I am using 2 the same bundles of which I renamed 1. That is giving this error. It should not happen in the full version, but I'd rather be able to actually fix it somehow in the code to not download 2 the same bundles.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same problem where unity was throwing the following error:

> Cannot load cached AssetBundle.
>   A file of the same name is already loaded from another AssetBundle

I was loading asset bundles at different stages of level but when I try to restart the level and try to load the asset bundle again I got the same error stated above. Then I tried saving the asset bundles in a list and trying to clear the list at level restart but that doesn't solved the problem. I even tried `Caching.CleanCache()` to remove any data from the memory but no use. I was saving the assets bundles on the disk after downloading and loading them again from the disk after level load.

**Solution:**

```
private IEnumerator LoadAssetFromFile(string _name) 
{ 
    print("Came inside LoadAssetFromFile :" + _name); 
    WWW www= new WWW(string.Concat("file:///", Application.dataPath, "/", _name +".unity3d"));//(m_savePath + _name); 
    //WWW www= new WWW(string.Concat(Application.dataPath, "/", _name));//(m_savePath + _name);

    yield return www;

    if(www.error == null)
    {
        //m_bundle =  www.assetBundle;
        AssetBundle bundle =  www.assetBundle;
        www.Dispose();
        www = null;
        string path = m_savePath + _name;
        //object [] obj = m_bundle.LoadAll();
        //for(int i=0; i< obj.Length; i++)
        //{
            //print ("Obj :"+ i +" " + obj[i].ToString());
        //}
        bundle.LoadAll();
        print ("AssetBundle is :" + bundle.mainAsset);
        print("============> " + path);
        GameObject _go =  (GameObject)Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset);
        bundle.Unload(false);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Using `bundle.Unload(false)` after instantiating the `gameObject` have done the trick.